# Keeping date style while column is formatted to text

Tags: excel, date, text, formatting, vba

I hope you can help. I am having an issue with formatting. 
The issue is this. 
In Pic 1 below you can see Column H. Column H needs to stay formatted as Text.  The date 03/14/2017 as text is 42808. What I need is the date to be text but remain in this style MM/DD/YYYY. Is there a formatting option that will allow 03/14/2017 to appear in this way and the cell to be text. 
I have tried custom  MM/DD/YYYY;@ but this formats the cell as date again not what i want. I know I could manually type in 03/14/2017 but I want to avoid manual work.

As always any and all help is greatly appreciated.

PIC. 1

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formula:

```
=TEXT(H2,"MM/DD/YYY")
```

VBA

```
ActiveSheet.Range("H2").Value = Format(ActiveSheet.Range("H2").Value2,"MM/DD/YYYY")
```

Comment: Hi Scott: Thank you so much. I actually knew this formula =TEXT(H2,"MM/DD/YYY") I Just straight up forgot about it. Thank you so much for  taking the time to respond and solve the issue. Much respect from Dublin :-)